# Make parallel concurrent calls to external apis from django

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have a django app (`django+python+apache mod_wsgi`) which act as a middleware between two systems, app gets requests from one system and it makes multiple requests to other apis to fetch and prepare the desired response, and then it passes the response to the requesting system.

So it's basically acting as a one-to-many middleware, problem is making calls sequentially is taking too much time, I tried to use threading for IO concurrency. However this is not working (I've read django works on single thread; correct me if I'm wrong), I've not worked with making requests in parallel on a webserver and have no idea how to do it.

Following is the current implementation :

```
   with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=MAX_BATCH_SIZE) as executor:
        future_to_url = {}
        for pnode in plist_node:
            config = {'url':rurl}
            futur = executor.submit(self.get_result_from_url, config)
```

Can someone please suggest the right way to do this ?

Comment: I'd say [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) is the way to go here. [Here](https://hackernoon.com/asynchronous-python-45df84b82434) is a nice introduction to this topic in Python.

Comment: @Borut how does asyncio helps in this ? Can you please explain ? I've to make X calls -> wait for there result -> join result -> respond. Will it help ?

Comment: It will run calls asynchronously. Instead of waiting for each call to finish before moving on to the next one, it will move on to the next one before the previous finishes. Once they're all complete, you join results and respond.

Comment: Using asyncio generally means you need to be running a web application that uses asyncio from the ground up. Using asyncio in the context of a threaded WSGI application is not so simple. OP should actually explain "this is not working". Impossible to say what is wrong with code without details or what occurs, what error happens etc.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, you are right. It won't work in the context of Django without something like Celery. But since the point is to make API calls faster, you probably can speed up this process by running asynchronous function inside a synchronous, or not? I did that once or twice, where Celery seemed like an overkill. It seemed to help with the execution time or was that just my imagination?